# Cancel function on mouse up?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how do i cancel/stop a function upon a mouse up event?

I basically have a onmousedown followed by a mousemove this lets me find a way to work out the offset amount with the mouse, but if i mouseup - it still keeps following the mouse!

I use:

```
function mousePos(e){  //gets the mouse position on click "start position"
    mousex = e.pageX;
    mousey = e.pageY;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", movePos, false);
}

function movePos(e){ // works out how far the mouse has moved from start position
    offset_x = mousex - e.pageX;
    offset_y = mousey - e.pageY;
}

//this is in my init function for body onload
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mousePos, false);
```

The problem i have is i need it to stop running once the button is no longer pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `mouseup` listener:

```
 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseFin, false);
```

Then in the `mouseup` listener, remove the `mousemove` listener:

```
function mouseFin(e) {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', movePos, false)
}
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/dATCA](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/dATCA/)**

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listener for mouseup and there remove the event listener for mousemove.

mouseup:

```
 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',onMouseUp,false);
```

and then in onMouseUp remove:

```
function onMouseUp(e) {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',movePos,false)
}
```

Comment: How do you remove the mousemove on mouseup though ? Do i use clear(mousemove) ?

Comment: @Dave you don't remove the handlers. You set a shared variable to true when the mouse is down, set it to false when the mouse is up, and only run the code inside the move handler if that variable is true..

Comment: But using a flag makes that your program is always calling the listener and checking the flag...

Comment: Hmm well the performance of my offset change is causing serious lag at the moment.